# Laravel Cashier webhook doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have followed the Laravel docs for adding Stripe webhooks and have created an endpoint in my Stripe webhook setting but still I get emails from Stripe saying they can't deliver data to webhook.

Below is the code i've added to my project for the webhook.

Route without middleware:

```
Route::post(
    'stripe/webhook',
    '\Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController@handleWebhook'
);
```

In verifyCsfToken.php:

```
protected $except = [
    'stripe/*',
];
```

Have I missed something or is this a common problem?

Answer (score 1):

Official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/billing#defining-webhook-event-handlers) says:

> Cashier automatically handles subscription cancellation on failed
>   charges, but if you have additional Stripe webhook events you would
>   like to handle, simply extend the Webhook controller. Your method
>   names should correspond to Cashier's expected convention,
>   specifically, methods should be prefixed with handle and the "camel
>   case" name of the Stripe webhook you wish to handle. For example, if
>   you wish to handle the invoice.payment_succeeded webhook, you should
>   add a handleInvoicePaymentSucceeded method to the controller.

I believe you are trying to handle custom webhook and that's the reason it is not working.

Comment: Okey i've missed that, but when a recurring subscription payment fails stripe doesnt set an enddate in DB and when the initial payment on a subscription fails the user it inserted into DB.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Artyom Sokolov's answer, I want to say, that there are two event: WebhookReceived and WebhookHandled.

WebhookReceived will be fired immediatelly, while WebhookHandled will be fired when it handled with a method you create (Check Artyom's answer)

Your listener may listen to WebhookReceived event, but sometimes it may be required listener to start to work when cashier made its job.

Also check config/cashier.php file for webhook.events array